# How to set the authentication in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, authentication

We have to manipulate the iis in our application,and we meet the `Access denied` error.

Then we add this to the web.config:

```
<identity userName="username" password="pass" impersonate="true"/>
```

It works,we can manipulate the iis(create virtual application and etc..).

However we have to access the shared folders in the application too,after add the above line,we can only access the shared folders on the machine which server our application.

If I remove the line from the web.config,we can access the shared folders from other servers.

So it seems that we can not manipulate the iis and access the shared folders at the same time.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give access to shared folders to the user that you have specified in the identity line in web.config because your web application is using those credentials to access the shared folders and it will only be possible if user specified there has access.

Or you can switch to windows authentication see [How To: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative to achieve the same.

Go to iis and set your application pool identity to user which has permissions to folder.

hope it will resolve your issue.